# Initialization of a union in C

Tags: c, initialization, unions

I came across this objective question on the C programming language. The output for the following code is supposed to be `0 2`, but I don't understand why.

Please explain the initialization process. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  union a
  {
    int x;
    char y[2];
  };
  union a z = {512};
  printf("\n%d %d", z.y[0], z.y[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the unexpected output that you get?

Comment: @Peter Mortensen your edit reversed the meaning of the question! It should be `The output is supposed to be 0 2. I dont' get why!`

Comment: @edc65 Exactly. I tried to fix that, but my suggested edit http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8336900 was rejected. If you also want to try it, maybe you will have better luck than me...

Comment: Note that the output from the printf() statement will be different depending on if the underlying hardware architecture is big Endian or little Endian.  The output could be (assuming a 32 bit or 64 bit architecture) (little Endian) '0 2' or (big Endian)  '0 0'.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I am going to assume that you use a little endian system where sizeof `int` is `4 bytes (32 bits)` and sizeof a `char` is `1 byte (8 bits)`, and one in which integers are represented in two's complement form. A `union` only has the size of its largest member, and all the members point to this exact piece of memory.

Now, you are writing to this memory an integer value of `512`.

512 in binary is `1000000000`.

or in 32 bit two's complement form:

`00000000 00000000 00000010 00000000`.

Now convert this to its little endian representation and you'll get:

```
00000000 00000010 00000000 00000000
|______| |______|
   |         |
  y[0]      y[1]
```

Now see the above what happens when you access it using indices of a `char` array.

Thus, `y[0]` is `00000000` which is `0`,

and `y[1]` is `00000010` which is `2`.

Comment: Thanks Arjun. I just didn't think about the binary representation. Now I get it. :)

Comment: Will accessing `y` beyond its bounds, but still inside the union (e.g. `y[3]`) be undefined behavior, similarly to normal array accesses?

Comment: @hexafraction AFAIK unless `sizeof(int)` < `3 * sizeof(char)`, `y[3]` is legal since it's just `*(y + 3)` and `y + 3` is a legal address occupied by the union.

Comment: @haccks no that's not the question. Probably you looked at the edited question. The question isn't very clear. But I assumed it's _Why is the output for the following code supposed to be `0 2`_ ? and I think OP's comment here vindicates my assumption.

Answer (score 8):

The memory allocated for the union is the size of the largest type in the union, which is `int`in this case. Let's say the size of `int` on your system is 2 bytes then

`512` will be `0x200`.

Represenataion looks like:

```
0000 0010 0000 0000
|        |         |
------------------- 
Byte 1     Byte 0
```

So the first byte is `0` and the second one is `2`.(On Little endian systems)

`char` is one byte on all systems.

So the access `z.y[0]` and `z.y[1]` is per byte access.

```
z.y[0] = 0000 0000 = 0
z.y[1] = 0000 0010 = 2
```

I am just giving you how memory is allocated and the value is stored.You need to consider the below points since the output depends on them.

**Points to be noted:**

1. The output is completely system dependent.
2. The [endianess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) and the `sizeof(int)` matters, which will vary across the systems.

PS: The memory occupied by both the members is the same in union.

Comment: Depends on the byte order.

Comment: Try this: `union a z={0x12345678};
    printf("\n%x %x",z.y[0],z.y[1]);` the output will be more demonstrative.

Comment: @WernerHenze: indeed, it only prints `0 2` on little endian systems.

Comment: It's worth mentioning, this assignment works because both the members of the union occupy the same location in memory

Comment: @Quirliom that depends on sizeof(int). A 32bit int on big endian system will produce `0 0` as output.

Comment: @user268396 I'm not saying anything about the result, only the fact that you can assign the int and access the chars.

Comment: Downvoting, for now: I doubt that the original poster will understand what happens from your answer. As it is, it just throws a couple of important buzzwords at the reader, without explaining them, multiple times (You wrote *three times* that byte order counts but didn't link to a page that explains what it is once..), and in a completely unstructured order, too.

Comment: @Phillip ok now i added the link to endianess explanation

Comment: Now I get it. Thank you everyone.

Comment: @SumitCornelius no probs

Comment: @KlasLindbäck: "Undefined behavior" and "implementation dependent" are [two very different terms defined by the C-standard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior) .  Without checking, I believe this is implementation dependent.

Answer (score 8):

The standard says that

#### 6.2.5 Types:

> A union type describes **an overlapping nonempty set of member objects**, each of which has an optionally specified name and possibly distinct type.

**The compiler allocates only enough space for the largest of the members, which overlay each other within this space**. In your case, memory is allocated for `int` data type (assuming 4-bytes). The line

```
union a z = {512};
```

will initialize the first member of union `z`, i.e. `x` becomes `512`. In binary it is represented as `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010 0000 0000` on a 32 machine.

Memory representation for this would depend on the machine architecture. On a 32-bit machine it either will be like (store the least significant byte in the smallest address-- **Little Endian**)

```
Address     Value
0x1000      0000 0000
0x1001      0000 0010
0x1002      0000 0000 
0x1003      0000 0000
```

or like (store the most significant byte in the smallest address -- **Big Endian**)

```
Address     Value
0x1000      0000 0000
0x1001      0000 0000
0x1002      0000 0010 
0x1003      0000 0000
```

`z.y[0]` will access the content at addrees `0x1000` and `z.y[1]`  will access the content at address `0x1001` and those content will depend on the above representation.
It seems that your machine supports Little Endian representation and therefore `z.y[0] = 0` and `z.y[1] = 2` and output would be `0 2`.

But, you should note that *footnote 95 of section 6.5.2.3* states that

> **If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to store a value in the object**, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted as an object representation in the new type as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called ‘‘type punning’’). **This might be a trap representation**.

Answer (score 1):

The size of the union is derived by the maximum size to hold a single element of it. So, here it is the size of int.

Assuming it to be 4 bytes/int and 1 bytes/char, we can say: `sizeof union a = 4 bytes`.

Now, let's see how it is actually stored in memory:

For example, an instance of the union, `a`, is stored at 2000-2003:

- 2000 -> last(4th / least significant / rightmost) byte of int x, y[0]
- 2001 -> 3rd byte of int x, y[1]
- 2002 -> 2nd byte of int x
- 2003 -> 1st byte of int x (most significant)

Now, when you say z=512:

since z = 0x00000200,

- M[2000] = 0x00
- M[2001] = 0x02
- M[2002] = 0x00
- M[2003] = 0x00

So, whey you print, y[0] and y[1], it will print data M[2000] and M[2001] which is 0 and 2 in decimal respectively.

Comment: Is the output based on hexadecimal interpretation or binary interpretation. Because it seems probable in both cases?

Comment: I've mentioned 0x to indicate Hex as per normal convention. Nothing is in binary. Can you please mention which line is confusing ?

Answer (score 0):

For automatic (non-static) members, the initialization is identical to assignment:

```
union a z;
z.x = 512;
```